# A collection which holds a specific number of values before being overwritten

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I need to use a Collection type in Java which will allow me to add values input by the user one at a time. When a new value is added it is added at index 0 and the previous index 0 value is moved to index 1 etc. Once there are 20 values I then want it to start replacing the 1st value, then the 2nd value and so on whilst moving the other values up 1 index.

i.e once all 20 values are filled, the next input becomes index 0, index 1 -> index 2 and so on. index 20 will be forgotten.

I have so far used an ArrayList of Integers but now I have come across this problem. I am wondering if another type of Collection would be best? The Collection will more than likely hold duplicate values.

From the 20 values I will want to sort in ascending order and then find the average of the top 8. I am currently doing that by copying to a second Arraylist within a method, sorting and then adding up the top 8 values and dividing by 8. This way the master list remains the same.

I am not sure there is an efficient way to do what I need with an arraylist.

Comment: `ArrayDeque` is probably more appropriate, making it easy to delete old elements from the beginning of the queue when its size exceeds a certain limit.  There are wrappers to make it even simpler in open-source libraries, like Guava's [`EvictingQueue`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html).

Comment: Smells like premature optimization.  If you only have 20 elements and are not doing the top-8-average thousands of times per second, what you have is probably "efficient" enough.

Comment: With a max size of 20 just removing the elements from the end of the list when it grows too large should be fine.